# Tomcat Application site asking for sign in

Tags: authentication, tomcat, tomcat9

I'm developing a simple web application deployed on tomcat. Every time I browsing my application on localhost:8080/myapp address from tomcat, a sign in pop up asking for tomcat user pass appears to allow me to browse the application. How could I prevent tomcat asking for sign in when loading application? My admin role is manager-gui and I set admin/admin for user/pass of tomcat manager.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat will only ask for authentication if you have specifically configured your application that way. You might want to look at the raw HTTP conversation to see what's happening. There may be a redirect or something else going on that you are not noticing.